# Which members of Rick's group have appeared in other TWD media?

Tags: the-walking-dead

We see Glenn and Herschel in "Season One" of Telltale Games' *The Walking Dead* story game;  a soon to be released spin off will focus on Michonne.

Which other members of Rick's group appear in other TWD media?

*For the purposes of this question, let's define "Rick's group" as the group Rick leads prior to their arrival at Alexandria. "Other media" means anything except the show and the comic books.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL; DR:

[image]

### Video Games:

#### [Telltale Games](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Video_Game_Characters):

- Glenn (Season One)
- Herschel (Season One)
- Michonne (Special)

#### [*Survival Instinct*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Survival_Instinct_Characters):

- Daryl
- Merle

#### [*Dead Reckoning*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Dead_Reckoning_Characters):

- Shane

#### [Social Game](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_Social_Game:_Chronicles):

- Rick
- Carl
- Lori
- Shane
- Glenn
- Merle
- Daryl
- Otis
- Andrea
- Michonne
- Morgan

#### [*Assault*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_Assault):

- Rick
- Lori
- Carl
- Glenn
- Shane
- Andrea
- Carol
- Sophia
- Dale
- Michonne
- Jim
- Herschel

#### [*Atlanta Run*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Road_to_Survival_Characters):

- Glenn

#### [*Road to Survival*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Road_to_Survival_Characters):

- Rick
- Lori
- Carl
- Judith
- Glenn
- Shane
- Andrea
- Amy
- Carol
- Sophia
- Dale
- Michonne
- Jim
- Herschel
- Maggie
- Billy
- Axel
- Morgan
- Tyreese
- Allen
- Otis
- Gabriel
- Abraham
- Rosita
- Eugene

#### [*No Man's Land*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_No_Man%27s_Land#Characters):

- Daryl

---

### [Print Novels](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Novel_Series_Characters):

- Tara ([*Rise of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_Rise_of_the_Governor))
- Bob  ([*The Road to Woodbury*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Road_to_Woodbury), [*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor), [*Descent*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_Descent), *[Invasion](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_Invasion)*)
- Rick ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Lori ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Carl ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Judith ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Andrea ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Sophia ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Michonne ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Glenn ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Dale ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Patricia ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Axel ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Tyreese ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Herschel ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Maggie ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))
- Billy ([*The Fall of the Governor*](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_The_Fall_of_the_Governor))